# c++ array to array assignment

Tags: c++, arrays

I wrote the following `employee` class:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class employee
{
    private:
        int id;
        int salaries[12];
        int annualS;
        string name;

    public:
        employee(int id2, string name2, int array[12])
        {
            id = id2;
            name=name2;
            salaries = array; //here where the error occurred.
        }
        ~employee()
        {
            cout<<"Object Destructed";
        }

        employee()
        {
            id = 0;
            name="Mhammad";
        }

        int annulalSalary()
        {
            for( int i=0; i<12; i++)
            {
                annualS+=salaries[i];
            }
            return annualS;
        }
        int tax()
        {
            return (annualS*10/100);
        }
};

void main()
{
    int salaries[12];
    for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        cin>>salaries[i];
    }

    employee Mohammad(10,"Mohammad",salaries);

    cout<< Mohammad.annulalSalary();
    cout<< Mohammad.tax();
}
```

...but when I compile it the, compiler returns the following error:

> ```
> cannot convert from 'int []' to 'int [12]'
> ```

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Use `std::array<T>` or `std::vector<T>`, they have `operator=` overloaded (amongst other things) which means you don't have to write the assignment code yourself.

Comment: the problem is the argument in your constructor. salaries cannot be declared to be of size 12. Instead, use `int* salaries`. But yes, you should be using vector<T>, much better and safer

Answer (score 0):

you can not copy an entire array just using = operator in c++. you have two options.

1. overload = operator
   or
2. use a for loop like this to copy each element of one array to another

   for(int i=0 ; i<12 ; i++)
       salaries[i]=array[i];

on a different note don't use magic numbers like 12 in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a C array, use the C++ `std::array<>`, like this:

```
class employee {
    //...
    std::array<int, 12> salaries;
    //...
};
```

and of course you'd have to include `<array>` too. And declare the constructor like this:

```
employee(int id2, string name2, std::array<int, 12> const & array)
{
    //...
}
```

(or drop the `const &` if you're not sure what they are or don't need them.)

Answer (score 0):

You can not copy arrays by assignment. You need to copy each element individually. Use `std::copy`.

```
std::copy(array, array+12, salaries);
```

Or use `std::vector<int>` or `std::array<int, 12>` as suggested by Borgleader which does copy by assignment.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. Forgot the `std::size_t` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Use the vector class!

But to solve your problem :

`int salaries[12]` should be `int* salaries`
`employee(int id2, string name2, int array[12])` should be `employee(int id2, string name2, int* array)`

but then you might a problems of referencing things outside the allocated memory and segfault. 
USE VECTORS!